# Access network volumes from PHP on Mac OS

Tags: macos, apache, webserver

I have a simply web-app running locally on my Mac, with PHP 7 and Apache.

This web-app executes this type of command (with exec() / system() command) in some of my web-projects:

*Project on network volume/folder*

```
sass /Volumes/htdocs/MYPROJECT1/scss/test.scss /Volumes/htdocs/MYPROJECT1/css/test.min.css -s compressed --no-source-map && postcss /Volumes/htdocs/MYPROJECT1/css/test.min.css --replace --use autoprefixer --no-map
```

*Project on Mac OS webserver*

```
sass /Library/WebServer/Documents/MYPROJECT2/scss/test.scss /Library/WebServer/Documents/MYPROJECT2/css/test.min.css -s compressed --no-source-map && postcss /Library/WebServer/Documents/MYPROJECT2/css/test.min.css --replace --use autoprefixer --no-map
```

Briefly: **compile certain SCSS files on my web projects**.

Some of these projects are on the local webserver of Mac OS (like the second example), and the commands are executed correctly (scss files are compiled). Others are located on a network volume/folder, which the Mac sees perfectly, shared by a Windows PC. **I can't compile, with php, the projects located in the network folder.**

---

By executing the first command, manually from the terminal, the command is executed correctly. So, I'm pretty sure it's a permissions issue of apache-php/ _www user.

From php i run these commands :

```
whoami -> _www

groups -> _www everyone localaccounts _lpoperator com.apple.sharepoint.group.1
```

---

I have tried various solutions found here on stackoverflow but none have solved the problem.
How is it possible to allow the user _www to access network volumes?

I believe that the user _www must have this permission, as has the terminal.

[image]

Current permission state of the folder Volumes (i'm interested in the htdocs folder)

[image]

### UPDATE1

It's a permission problem, confirmed.

php error_log

```
Error reading ../../../../../Volumes/htdocs/MYPROJECT1/scss/test.scss: permission denied.
```

### UPDATE 2

I tried to change the user in **httpd.conf**, but the permission problems remain

```
#User _www
#Group _www
User dev
Group staff
```

### UPDATE 3

Following the commands described [here](https://blog.travismclarke.com/post/osx-cli-group-management/), i have created a new Users Group with name **TestSCSS**, with 2 users : **dev** (my mac user) and **_www**. Now i'm trying to change the permissions to the folders **/Volumes/htdocs** (the folder shared by windows that the mac sees), trying to add the new **TestSCSS** group. But after entering the group name, the group name is not inserted here.

[image]

Comment: How are you mounting the volume? And how is the remote volume shared, eg if another computer what protocol and perms is it exporting with?  Unrelated and probably not important, but why all the `../../../../../` in the error msg?  The commands you show don't include that, and you don't need relative paths to get to `/Volumes/`?

Comment: From Mac, i see the shared folder as a PC (in the Network section). I log into that PC / Folder as a username and password (the user account is saved and the login is automatic). The folder is a simple folder shared by a windows computer. The commands are executed using the path /Volumes/... , the various ../../, are added by php.

Comment: You're logging in to the share with a u/p, and the permissions that Mac user has are controlled by the Windows share.  On the Win computer, look a the settings for that share - can you grant your user full permissions?  Try right-clicking the share (on Win) and looking for sharing settings.

Comment: The user i use to access the shared folder from Windows has full permissions. I've always worked on that folder from Mac, editing and creating files.

Comment: For this reason the problem i think is more a problem of apache permissions (Mac). And as mentioned, from the terminal (Mac), I can easily compile the projects present on the shared folder of Windows.

Comment: OK, so you need to grant write permissions to the `_www` user, or make the dir/files group-writeable and add write permission for the `_www` group.  Eg maybe instead of connecting as your Mac user, connect as `_www`, and make sure that user has full permissions.  Of course if you do that it means your Mac user will *not* have writer perms.  If you want both users to be able to write, you need to set up a group that both users are members of with write perms, and make the dir/files group-writable.

Comment: Could be wrong, but I think you are setting perms on the wrong machine...
i.e. the permissions in question are on the folder shared by the Windows PC.
To test this, edit the permissions on the share on the Windows PC and grant the "Everyone group" "read" and try and execute the command again.

Comment: Were you able to update perms on the share?

Comment: UPDATE 3 added ..

Comment: It isn't completely clear what the screenshot is showing, but it looks like part of the file sharing window on macOS?  That's what you'd use if you are trying to share something on your Mac to other computers on your network.  It is not relevant for files being shared from the Win machine.  Try the simplest option first - on the Win share, grant every user who connects full (r/w) permissions (check the share settings on the Win machine).  Then from the Mac, connect to it as your new dev user (or any user).  If that works, try reducing the permissions to just the users/groups you want.

Comment: The image shows the permissions that the Volume htdocs has on Mac. htdocs it's the Windows folder that is shared. On Windows the htdocs folder is accessible to all users.